# When should I create the alternative images with different dimensions?

Tags: php, laravel, image, intervention

Currently when I upload an image on my website, I create 3 alternative images with different dimensions in my `uploadImage();` function. I've been wondering if it is possible to create the images on demand only.

For example, only create 500px width version only when a user visits the route that actually requires this image. This way I wouldn't have to save all 4 images during the upload ( which I assume slows it down ) and I wouldn't have to save an image which might never be requested.

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:120',
            'description' => 'max:120|nullable',
            'image' => 'required'
        ]);

        $name = $request['name'];
        $description = $request['description'];
        $tag = $request['tags'];
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
        $file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);

        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/specificImages/',$fileNameToStore);
        $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/uploads/images/miniImages/',$fileNameToStore);

        $thumbnail = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$fileNameToStore )->resize(500, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $thumbnail->save();

        $specificImage = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$fileNameToStore )->resize(1240, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $specificImage->save();

        $miniImage = InterventionImage::make('storage/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$fileNameToStore )->fit(200, 200, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        });

        $miniImage->save();

        $image = new Image();
        $image->name = $name;
        $image->description = $description;
        $image->user_id = $userId;
        $image->file_name = $fileNameToStore;

        $image->save();
        $image->tags()->attach($tag);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

My View that displays 500px image:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="specificStickyContainer">
    <h1 class='specificImageTitle'>{{$image->name}} by <a href='{{url("profile/".$author->username )}}'>{{$author->username}}</a></h1>
    <img class='specific-image' src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
    @if(Auth::user())
        @if(Auth::id() === $image->user_id || Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
        <div class='deleteButton'></div>
        <a class='deleteA' href='{{ route('deleteImage', ['image_id' => $image->id]) }}'>X</a>
        @endif
    @endif
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Yes, make the `src="somescript.php?whichfile=filename"` and in that script resize and send the new image

Comment: On-the-fly thumbnails were rather popular in the early days but I don't think they make sense today. An image is uploaded once and downloaded many times—and if it's never requested it means it's a rare link or a low traffic site and performance/scalability is not an issue anyway.

Comment: So would you say I should create all alternatives during the upload?

Comment: I would say stick to creating the variations during the upload until it starts to becomes an issue. If you want to speed up the upload time for your users, you could always create a job and queue it rather than doing it during the request.

Comment: And what is the best course of action when it becomes an issue? I'm really trying to pick up good practices from now and not wait until it's already causing issues.

Comment: I suggest creating alternatives _once_ — not necessarily in the same request than the upload. But we're talking about resizing pictures, not re-encoding video; how long can it take?